# max-width is pushing other items off the page

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a scalable image on my website to make it mobile-friendly. I tried using max-width 100% and then set the height to auto, but that just pushed the text to the right of the screen. I tried to fix this by setting the text width to 66%, but that did nothing. I tried setting the width of the image to 33%, but when I did that the height auto stretched the image.

```css
.bodyAboutMe {
  background-color: #1e1e1e;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 10px 100px;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
}

.bodyAboutMe img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.textAboutMe {
  width: 66%;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.bodyAboutMe h1 {
  padding-top: 25px;
  font-family: 'AboutMeFont';
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  font-size: 1000%;
}

.bodyAboutMe p {
  padding: 50px 150px;
  font-size: 150%;
}
```

```html
<section class="bodyAboutMe">
  <img src="images/20210926_071241.jpg">
  <div class="textAboutMe">
    <h1>About Me</h1>
    <p>about me text</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

[Website snip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1lak.jpg)

Comment: you want image side by side with text or text below of the image ?

Comment: I want the text side by side with the image.

Comment: then you can't have `font-size: 1000%` that's HUGE, and thats the problem not the image

Comment: It isn't though because the image takes up all of the screen and the text is off to the side. Also, it really isn't that big because the font is super small.

Comment: Then create a working snippet with real font and real image

Comment: I can't post a snip, but basically, the image looks like a background taking up all of the screen. I know it's not the font in any way or form because I had everything working when I set the image to a set size of 500x500px. I am trying to make it dynamic now, but it isn't working

Comment: you can't why??

Comment: I figured it out. Refresh for snip.

Comment: and you don't see in this snippet the font is huge ??

Comment: @BrandonLaliberte please use a valid link of image and font.

Comment: My website is bloodypk.com if you want to check it. It has the valid font and image. I haven't pushed the changes of image size yet to that, but if the font size was the issue then that wouldn't be formatted right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Since you what to keep them aside they cant be each 100%** they shoud be both 100% width so changin the **max-width to 50%** fixes the problem with the mobile.
If you dont want your image to be streached **use object-fit:cover;** or scale-down

```css
.bodyAboutMe {
  background-color: #1e1e1e;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 10px 100px;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
}

.bodyAboutMe img {
  max-width: 50%;
  object-fit: cover;
  height: auto;
}

.textAboutMe {
  width: 66%;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.bodyAboutMe h1 {
  padding-top: 25px;
  font-family: 'AboutMeFont';
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  font-size: 100%;
}

.bodyAboutMe p {
  padding: 50px 150px;
  font-size: 150%;
}
```

```html
<section class="bodyAboutMe">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1lak.jpg">
  <div class="textAboutMe">
    <h1>About Me</h1>
    <p>about me text</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I added object-fit: scale-down; and that fixed it. Thanks dude.